# Vbscript compiling error when running VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

So my problem is that I can't get the VBScript to work. I want to automate this macro using the VBScript written in this post, which should execute the VBA code below. The error message I receive is in line 2, where the error is that the file couldn't be found. The VBScript and the test.xlsm file is in the same folder. How can I access the test.xlsm file without an error?

My VBA code so far:

```
Sub copySchedule()

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:F10").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F10")
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

My VBScript code so far:

```vb
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Run ""test.xlsm!copySchedule""

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Too many quotes: `objExcel.Application.Run "test.xlsm!copySchedule"`

Comment: Read another question where someone said to put multiple quotes around the run string. But will try that. It fixed the compiling error, but the vbscript now fails in line 2 where it cant find the test.xlsm file, although the vbscript is in the same folder as the test.xlsm file. See updated question

Comment: You put multiple quotes *inside* a string to tell that you want a quote character in that string.

Comment: Okay thanks, my bad. The question have been updated :)

Comment: Include the full path in the `Workbooks.Open` call

Comment: Thank you so much @Rory ! Will you answer the question with the updates so i can give you a checkmark. Really thanks for helping, have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only needed one pair of quotes round the macro name (if the workbook name contained spaces, you would need apostrophes round the name, and you can use them anyway if you like) and you should include the full file path when opening the workbook. So, for example:

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\some folder\test.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Run "'test.xlsm!copySchedule'"
```

Comment: The correct answer, just a shame the OP [edited their code in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71320121/2) as it invalidates this answer. Have [revised the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71320121/4) to bring it back in line with the original code that was posted.